# What is the class that implement the CallLog ListView in android source code?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

What is the class that implement the ListView in CallLog? I mean I have all this package: [platform/packages/apps/Contacts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts).

But I dont know what class in this package implements the CallLog activity, the list of recent callings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's [RecentCallsListActivity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/contacts/RecentCallsListActivity.java).